# Run Time Error: 462 Remote Server Does Not Exist or is Unavailable

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

Have looked through multiple instances on here but can't seem to find one that matches mine. I am getting the following error "Run Time Error 462: The remote server machines does not exist or is unavailable." for the below line of code:

```
Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(CntListatPortEmail)
```

I have ran this code multiple times but it seems when it gets to the end, around the 4th or 5th time, it'll just shut down.

Comment: One line of code isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not keeping a template on the local hard drive. You need to have a .oft file saved somewhere on your hard drive to get the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method running correctly. Note that you can save an existing e-mail item as a template using the `File | Save As…` command in Outlook. You just need to choose the "Outlook Template" in the `Save as type` list box of the `Save As` dialog. Alternatively, you can do the same programmatically by specifying the `Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olTemplate` value in the `SaveAs` method of Outlook items.